# Display table records order by time in descending

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am displaying table records with below code.The records are displaying but not in proper order(asc/desc).

```
// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 =>'***', 
    1 => '***',
    2=> '***',
        3=> 'time',
        4=> '***'
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * ";
$sql.=" FROM details where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id'];

$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("server_response.php: get details");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql = "SELECT * ";
$sql.=" FROM details where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id'];
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
    $sql.=" AND ( *** LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $sql.=" OR *** LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR *** LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR time LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";

    $sql.=" OR *** LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("server_response.php: get details");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['dir'][0]['order'] contains order such as asc/desc  */    
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("server_response.php: get details");

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $row[""];
    $nestedData[] = $row[""];
    $nestedData[] = $row[""];
        $nestedData[] = $row["time"];
        $nestedData[] = $row[""];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

I need to display records in descending order by time. How can I Sort the record to descending order?

Comment: Please add a log statement to your code to show the final query string that is being executed after the parameters have been applied, and then [edit] your question to show us that query string. And speaking of the parameters, [**do not concatenate request params into an SQL string!**](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write mysql query to order by time as descending

```
SELECT something , something FROM mytable ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: That is not working in this case. Need to change here.

Comment: do your query is working and you have the out put..? you want to make that output as descending order by time ?

Comment: Yes.I am getting out put. Only records are not in desc order. Want to display records in desc order by time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your PHP It will be helpfull to you

```
$json = '[{"date": "2011-08-07", "name": "bob"},{"date": "2011-07-07", "name": "jones"},{"date": "2011-09-03", "name": "blair"},{"date": "2009-01-01", "name": "test"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo 'Before Sorting <br>';
print_r($arr);
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['date'], $b['date']);
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
echo "<br><br> After Sorting <br>";
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: OP is trying to sort within an SQL query.